# Adding attribute headerClass into display:column

Tags: jquery, displaytag

I would like to hide an entire column in my displaytag table using jQuery. I have assigned the `<display:column>` tag with the `class='col0'` and I am able to hide the data rows using `$('.col0').addClass('hidden')`.

However, for the table header, I tried inserting attribute by using `$('.col0').attr('headerClass', 'hidden')` but it doesn't assign the attribute to the table header. Is there any other ways so I can add the headerClass attribute to the display column?

Edited to add code snippet:

```
<display:table name="..." class="table simple" pagesize="20" export="false" sort="list" bundle="..." optimised="true" decorator="...">
    <display:column property="dob" key="personnel.html.dateOfBirth" class="col0" headerClass=""/>
<display:table>

<script>
    //function toggled by checkbox onchange='toggleColumns(this.id)'
    function toggleColumns(obj) {
        if($('#'+obj).attr('checked')){
             $('.'+obj).removeClass('hidden');
             $('.'+obj).attr('headerClass', '');
        } else {
             $('.'+obj).addClass('hide');
             $('.'+obj).attr('headerClass', 'hidden');
        }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Is headerClass an attribute for the <display: column>, could you please share the code snippet to resolve the issue.
```

Comment: Thanks. I have solved my problem by providing the same class name. Initially thought that the value for headerClass could only be of value 'hidden' or empty.